# Creating an ASP.net MVC Web Application with details given below:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, image, file-upload

To take the image from user and save image of users table in the database.
To add a view to show images of users from the folder `Images` in the Listing View of user along with other information of user.

Now the reason for this question is that when I tried to save it in database it saves the images successfully but not in the `Images` folder I tried everything but none of the method works.

My Code:

`Employee` Controller:

```
using My_Work.DAL;
using My_Work.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PagedList;
using PagedList.Mvc;
using System.IO;

namespace My_Work.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index(string SearchBy, string SearchTerm,
       int? page, string sortBy)
        {
            //In case of Invalid user redirect to login
            if (Session["login"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }
            ViewBag.CitySort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "City desc" : "City";
            ViewBag.GenderSort = sortBy == "Gender" ? "Gender desc" : "Gender";
            EmployeeEntity entity = new EmployeeEntity();
            List<Employee> list = entity.GetList(SearchBy,
           SearchTerm, sortBy);
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Detalis"];
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                string color = cookie["Lastlogin"];
            }

            return View(list.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
        }
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            //In case of Invalid user redirect to login
            if (Session["login"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }
            ViewBag.DepartmentsList = getDepartmentList();
            //ViewBag.LanguagesList = GetLanguagesList();
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {
            if (Session["login"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var allowedExtensions = new[] {".Jpg", ".png", ".jpg", "jpeg"};
                var ext = Path.GetExtension(employee.file.FileName);
                //getting the extension(ex-.jpg)
                if (allowedExtensions.Contains(ext)) //check what type of extension
                {
                    //~/Images is relative path for images in root directory
                   var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"),Path.GetFileName(employee.file.FileName));
                    employee.ImageURL = employee.file.FileName;
                    //saving photo of employee in the image folder
                    // file.SaveAs Saves the contents of an uploaded file to a specified path on the Web server.
                     employee.file.SaveAs(path);
                }
               else
               {
                    ViewBag.message = "Please choose only Image file";
                    ViewBag.DepartmentsList = getDepartmentList();
                    return View(employee);
               }
               EmployeeEntity entity = new EmployeeEntity();
               int count = entity.insert(employee);
               if (count > 0)
               {
                    ViewBag.successMessage = "Data insterted Successfully !";
               }
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            ViewBag.DepartmentsList = getDepartmentList();
            return View(employee);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(long id)
        {
            //In case of Invalid user redirect to login
            if (Session["login"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }
            EmployeeEntity entity = new EmployeeEntity();
            int RowCount = entity.DeleteEmployee(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            //In case of Invalid user redirect to login
            if (Session["login"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }
            Employee emp = new EmployeeEntity().GetSingleEmployee(id);
            ViewBag.DepartmentsList = getDepartmentList();
            return View(emp);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
        {
            //In case of Invalid user redirect to login
            if (Session["login"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }
            int RowCount = new
           EmployeeEntity().UpdateEmployee(employee);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        private List<SelectListItem> getDepartmentList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> departmentList = new
           Department().getDepartmentList();

            return departmentList;
        }

    }
}
```

`Employee` Model:

```
using My_Work.CustomValidation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace My_Work.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(20, 60, ErrorMessage = "Age must be between 20 and  60")]
        [Display(Name = "Age")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Education Level")]
        public int EducationLevel { get; set; }
        [Range(25000, 500000, ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct value")]
        [Required]
        /* We can control the display of data in a View (UI) using
       display attributes */
        [Display(Name = "Salary")]
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter hire date")]
        [Display(Name = "Hire Date")]
        [CustomHireDate(ErrorMessage = "Hire Date must be less than or equal to Today's Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public Department department { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Upload Photo")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }

    }
}
```

`EmployeeEntity` Class:

```
using My_Work.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;

namespace My_Work.DAL
{
    public class EmployeeEntity
    {
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        public int insert(Employee employee)
        {
            int effectedRows = 0;
            try
            {
                sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                string query = @"insert into Employee(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Age,EducationLevel,Salary,EmailAddress,HireDate,
                City,DepartmentID,ImageURL)
                values('" + employee.EmployeeID + "','" + employee.FirstName + "','"
                + employee.LastName + "','" + employee.Gender + "','" + employee.Age +
                "','" + employee.EducationLevel + "','" + employee.Salary + "','" +
                employee.EmailAddress + "','" + employee.HireDate + "','" +
                employee.City + "','" + employee.department.DepartmentID +
                "','" + employee.ImageURL + "')";
                sqlConnection.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
                effectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConnection.Close();
                return effectedRows;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                return effectedRows;
            }
        }
        public List<Employee> GetList(string searchBy, string search, string sortBy)
        {
            //Here we have passed searchBy and Search as parameters and we are
            // going to apply where filter in SQL Query using these parameters
            List<Employee> employeesList = new List<Employee>();
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            string query = String.Empty;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
            {
                sortBy = "City";
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy))
            {
                query = @"select * from Employee inner join Department on Employee.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID where "
                + searchBy + " like '%" + search + "%'order by "+sortBy+"";
            }
            else
            {
                query = @"select * from Employee inner join Department on Employee.DepartmentID =
                Department.DepartmentID order by " + sortBy + "";
            }
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                employeesList.Add(new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["EmployeeId"].ToString()),
                    FirstName = dataReader["FirstName"].ToString(),
                    LastName = dataReader["LastName"].ToString(),
                    Gender = dataReader["Gender"].ToString(),
                    City = dataReader["City"].ToString(),
                    EmailAddress = dataReader["EmailAddress"].ToString(),
                    Age = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Age"].ToString()),
                    Salary = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Salary"].ToString()),
                    EducationLevel = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["EducationLevel"].ToString()),
                    HireDate = DateTime.Parse(dataReader["HireDate"].ToString()),
                    ImageURL = dataReader["ImageURL"].ToString(),
                    department = new Department
                    {
                        DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["departmentId"].ToString()),
                        Name = dataReader["Name"].ToString()
                    }
                });
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
            return employeesList;
        }
        public List<Employee> GetList()
        {
            List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            string query = @"select * from Employee emp inner join Department dept on emp.DepartmentID=dept.DepartmentID";
            sqlConnection.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
            SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                EmployeeList.Add(new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = dataReader["FirstName"].ToString(),
                    LastName = dataReader["LastName"].ToString(),
                    Gender = dataReader["Gender"].ToString(),
                    EmailAddress =
               dataReader["EmailAddress"].ToString(),
                    City = dataReader["City"].ToString(),
                    Salary
               = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Salary"].ToString()),
                    Age =
               Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Age"].ToString()),
                    EducationLevel =
               Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["EducationLevel"].ToString()),
                    department = new Department
                    {
                        DepartmentID =
               Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["DepartmentID"].ToString()),
                        Name = dataReader["Name"].ToString()
                    },
                    HireDate =
               DateTime.Parse(dataReader["HireDate"].ToString())
                });
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
            return EmployeeList;
        }
    }
}
```

`Create` View:

```
@model My_Work.Models.Employee
{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Employee Information</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new
    { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4 class="h1 text-center">Create Employee</h4>
            <hr />
            <div>
                @if (ViewBag.successMessage != null)
                {
                    <h3>@ViewBag.successMessage</h3>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes:
               new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new {
                   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName,
                   "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes:
               new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new {
                   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName,
                   "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new
               { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender, new {
                   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "",
                   new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress,
               htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new {
                   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>
                   model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new {
               @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new {
                   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "",
                   new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary, htmlAttributes: new
               { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary, new {
                   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salary, "",
                   new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new {
               @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new {
                   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new
                   { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EducationLevel,
               htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EducationLevel, new {
                   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>
                   model.EducationLevel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HireDate, htmlAttributes:
               new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HireDate, new {
                   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HireDate,
                   "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.department.DepartmentID,
               htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>
                   model.department.DepartmentID,
                   (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DepartmentsList)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.file, htmlAttributes: new {
               @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file, new { type = "file",
                   @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.file, "",
                   new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btndefault" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to Main Page", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`Index` View:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
@model IPagedList<My_Work.Models.Employee>
@{
    Layout = null;
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Detalis"];
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float:left">
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        @{
            String img64 = (string)Session["userImage"];
            String img64Url = string.Format("data:image/" +
           (string)Session["userImageType"] + ";base64,{0}", img64);
            //imagetype can be e.g. gif, jpeg, png etc.
        }
        <img alt="" src="@img64Url" width="40" height="40"
             class="rounded-circle" />
        <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Click to Logout", "Logout", "User")
    </div>
    <br />
    <p>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("Customize", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <b>User Preferences:</b>
            @Html.TextBox("RecordCount")
            <input type="submit" value="Set Preferences" />
        }
    </p>
    <p>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Employee", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <b>Search By:</b>
            @Html.RadioButton("SearchBy", "City", true)
            <text>City</text>
            @Html.RadioButton("SearchBy", "Gender")
            <text>Gender</text><br />
            @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit"
                                           value="search" />
        }
    </p>
    <p>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>
                   model.First().FirstName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>
                   model.First().EmailAddress)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Gender", "Index", new
                    {
                   sortBy = ViewBag.GenderSort,
                    SearchBy = Request["SearchBy"],
                    SearchTerm = Request["SearchTerm"]
                    })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("City", "Index", new
                    {
                    sortBy = ViewBag.CitySort,
                    SearchBy = Request["SearchBy"],
                    SearchTerm = Request["SearchTerm"]
                    })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>
                   model.First().HireDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Photo
                </th>
            </tr>
            @if (Model.Count() == 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        No records match search criteria
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Employee", new
                    {
                        id = item.EmployeeID
                    }))
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAddress)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HireDate)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ImageURL))
                                {
                                    @*@Url.Content convert the relative path into application absolute
                                    path*@
                                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/" + item.ImageURL)"
                                         height="50px" width="50px" />
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span>No Image Found!</span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id =
                               item.EmployeeID }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id =
                               item.EmployeeID }) |
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('do you really want to delete this record?');" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
        </table>
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {
       page, SearchBy = Request.QueryString["SearchBy"], SearchTerm =
       Request.QueryString["SearchTerm"], sortBy =
       Request.QueryString["sortBy"] }), new PagedListRenderOptions() {
       Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
       DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true })
        <br />
        <div style="float:left">
            <dl>
                <dt>
                    @Html.ActionLink("User Last Login:", cookie["Lastlogin"])
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    @if (cookie != null)
                    {
                        @cookie["Lastlogin"];
                    }
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <br />
</body>
</html>
```

`Images` Folder:

[image]

Comment: This is way too much to read imo.

Comment: can you upload your source code ?

Comment: @TaW yeah I know this is too much to read cause I also cannot get the error why the image is not storing on Images folder.

Comment: @Sign I already shared the code in which I implement all the things.